# Pandas - Column with formula

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In a Pandas DataFrame, Is it possible to create a new column and apply a condition (like if statement) checking another column value in order to return a value?

Follow a example below:

```
Column_A
ABC
1
2
3
4
5
DEF
6
7
8
9
10
```

Then an condition for Column_B (if statement or something similar...)

```
if Column_A is str:
    var = Column_A
    Column_B = var
elif
    Column_B = var
```

expected result

```
Column_A Column_B: 
ABC      ABC
1        ABC
2        ABC
3        ABC
4        ABC
5        ABC
DEF      DEF
6        DEF
7        DEF
8        DEF
9        DEF
10       DEF
```

Comment: Do you know anything about the type of the non `str` values? Are they necessarily numbers? Pandas can only have one data type per column this is not possible in the most general context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `isalpha` and assign the value then `ffill`

```
df['Column_B']=df.loc[df.Column_A.str.isalpha(),'Column_A']
df.Column_B.ffill(inplace=True)
```